# How to extract data from different columns of a PySpark dataframe in different python lists or dict?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, collect

I want to extract all different columns of a pyspark dataframe in either different python lists (maintaining the correspondence) or a python dictionary.

How do I do it?

the only want I know to do is-

```
colA_list = [i.colA for i in df.select("colA").collect()]
colB_list = [i.colB for i in df.select("colB").collect()]
```

Does this method ensure correct ordering? If not what the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

df.columns provides u the list of the columns in the order of dataframe

```
col = df.columns
```

Comment: I want the elements of the columns and not the names of the columns. And I want it in such a way that all the elements in different lists (for different columns) have their order maintained in them